# How to move a html5 canvas element(rectangle) by touching it by onTouch method

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a rectangle inside a canvas and i want to move it right side by touching this rectangle.it may just like draging rectangle along a straight line.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Update the coordinates of the rectangle with the coordinates of where you touch? Question lacks personal effort, expand it please.

Comment: Sounds like you need SVG - not Canvas.